# Use arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer to remove layers that are defined in list?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, layers

I can't seem to find anything as far as defining a list of layer names and then removing those layers from all mxds within a folder. This is the code I have worked up so far, but I have to cut and paste a new entry for each new layer name. Just getting into programming. I poached a lot of this and made it work for what I needed.

ArcGIS 10.3.1

Windows 10

---

This is my final product following everyone's advice.

```
#import modules
import os, arcpy

#provide project folder path
folderPath = "C:\Project Folder"
#define list of layers to be removed from mxd files as the name appears in table of contents
LayersToRemove = ['layer 1','layer 2']
for fileName in [x for x in os.listdir(folderPath) if os.path.splitext(x)[1] == ".mxd"]:
    fullPath = os.path.join(folderPath, fileName)
    if os.path.isfile(fullPath):
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fullPath)
        print(fileName)
        for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd):
            for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
                if lyr.name in LayersToRemove:
                    arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
                    print("     " + df.name + ": removed: " + lyr.name)
        #saves a copy of the map
        mxd.saveACopy("copy_" + fileName)
        del mxd
```

Comment: Perhaps define your list of names above e.g. `layersToRemove = ['Layer 1', 'Layer 2', 'Layer 3']` and then change the `if lyr.name == 'Layer x':` to `if lyr.name in layersToRemove:`

Comment: @smiller, you should probably put that in an answer as it is correct.

Comment: Be careful you don't have duplicate layer names.

Comment: Your `folderPath` isn't valid, since the backslashes are not escaped or overridden by raw formatting.

Comment: @Vince good point

Comment: Please don't include answers (solutions) in your question, that is what the answer area of each Q&A is for.  It is fine and encouraged to self-answer questions.  It's not too late to cut/paste your answer from your question into a proper answer.  It may help gain you some rep with which to unlock additional site functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your list of names above e.g. `layersToRemove = ['Layer 1', 'Layer 2', 'Layer 3']` and then change the `if lyr.name == 'Layer x':` to `if lyr.name in layersToRemove:`

Answer (score 1):

here is some code I wrote a few months ago that will crawl through network drives and open up mxds to remove certain layers you want.

```
import arcpy,os,fnmatch,sys

def find(pattern, path=os.getcwd()):
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for filename in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, pattern): yield os.path.abspath(os.path.join(path, filename))


for f in find('*.mxd',r'path'):
    mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r'{}'.format(f))
    print mxd
    for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd):
        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,data_frame=df):
            print lyr
            if lyr.name in("layer1","layer2"):
                arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df,lyr)
    mxd.save()
```

just replace `'path'` with your path and repalce `"layer1","layer2"` with the layers you want to remove.